# Split matrix according to specified order of values

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix

Sorry if this question's been asked before, but I can't seem to find an applicable answer!

I have this sort of matrix in Matlab:

```
1  0.2   0.3    1  5
1  0.25  0.36   1  6
1  0.3   0.3   -1  5
2  0.1   0.3    1  5
2  0.3   0.3   -1  5
2  0.6   0.4   -1  9 ......
```

The matrix is actually much longer and goes on to a value of 346 in the first column.

How can I split the matrix up into smaller matrices according to a specific order of the values in the first column? For example, I need the matrix of all the values where the first column = 160, 130, 256, 2 in that order?

Comment: To attract more answers, you should add a tag corresponding to the language or tools you are using. You can do that by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11631073/edit) and adding tags at the bottom of the edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with `grep`:

```
grep -E '^(160|130|256|2)[ \t]'
```

#### Update

In `matlab` you could use the comparison operator, e.g. if `data` is the matrix:

```
 data(data(:, 1) == 1, :)
```

Will return the sub-matrix where the first column value is one. To apply it to your example something like this would do:

```
subm = [];
for i=[160, 130, 256, 2]
   subm = [subm; data(data(:, 1) == i, :);
end
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to say it was in matlab

Comment: Amended the answer with a matlab version

Answer (score 3):

Say M is your MatLab matrix. Then find(M(:,1) == 7) gives you the indices of those rows you are looking for. Also, you may do something like M(M(:,1) == 7,:) to access the corresponding submatrix